# Get chain of certificates for a file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, certificate, pki, authenticode

I am looking for a method, using PowerShell only, to list the certificate chain for signed files. Specifically to get the Root certificate.

As I need to get a list of which Non-Microsoft root certificates certain executables (on installed software), are dependent on. This is due to a OS-baseline guidelines, that uses the PKI procedure in Microsoft KB293781. Where only specific Root certificates shall be put on specific computers. E.g the much used "VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5", shall only be used when necessary.

Get-AuthenticodeSignature only lists the Issuer. E.g: `Get-AuthenticodeSignature C:\windows\system32\MRT.exe`

Tools like "SysInternals SigCheck" is able to do this `sigcheck.exe -i C:\windows\System32\mrt.exe`, and this infomation can be parsed further on. Also other tools like `SignTool.exe` from the Windows SDK, and `AnalyzePESig` by Didier Stevens can get this info.

But can this be done using only PowerShell? Perhaps using the WinVerifyTrust API in Windows.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382384(v=vs.85).aspx
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/323809/en-us

Cheers,
Tekk

Answer (score 11):

This should be possible by accessing .NET directly in PowerShell. Here's a snippet I whipped up using the example file you had referenced in your question:

```
# Get a X590Certificate2 certificate object for a file
$cert = (Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\windows\system32\MRT.exe).SignerCertificate
# Create a new chain to store the certificate chain
$chain = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
# Build the certificate chain from the file certificate
$chain.Build($cert)
# Return the list of certificates in the chain (the root will be the last one)
$chain.ChainElements | ForEach-Object {$_.Certificate}
```

Does that give you what you were looking for?

Comment: This method only appears to work if Windows is connected to the internet, and able to resolve CTLs / OCSP, which is not possible in the environment
Turned on logging for CAPI2 in Event Viewer, and got following (shortened):

<code>
Name: Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2 
EventID: 30 
UserData 
  - Result A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority. 

EventID: 11
  - RevocationResult The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline. 
  - Result A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority. 
</code>