# Certificate exported from Windows CA store is unreadable by Java

Tags: java, powershell, certificate, keytool, pkcs#12

I'm exporting a certificate from the Windows CA certificate store using a method nearly identical to the answer here:
[Get chain of certificates for a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101140/get-chain-of-certificates-for-a-file-with-powershell) and here [Automate export x509 certificate w/chain from Server 2008 R2 to a p7b file WITHOUT external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512409/automate-export-x509-certificate-w-chain-from-server-2008-r2-to-a-p7b-file-witho) Except I am getting it from the CA system store.

This works, and things like openssl and certutil can read my certificate. However, I need Java to read my certificate, and both the Java 8 keystore class and the keytool command line tool ( `keytool -list -v -keystore v.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass pass` ) say that my certificate has 0 entries, whereas openssl and certutil show there are entries.

How can I either export my certificate in a Java readable format, or easily convert it to a Java readable format while keeping it in pkcs12? The machine  I actually want to export on doesn't have openssl, so please keep that in mind. An example file (password is 'pass') is here: https://mega.nz/#!Cj5GGIBR!O5shbaPuHNKEJhRrivR0TY3hRd3ZRYQzvRQFJa_ri3s

Answer (score -1):

Import the PKCS12 data into a JKS keystore:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore v.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore v.jks
```

Comment: `Import command completed:  0 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled.` Java tools seem unable to work with the keystore, but it does recognize bad passwords and the like